# Css Html div resize to fit, but not resize the image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

Hi I am trying to make a resizable div (gallery of photos to my site) to fit but not deform the background image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoXKt.png)

To work in multiple screens, I found a perfect example https://popcorntime-online.io/

How can I make this?

Comment: maybe you should turn to [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: If this example is perfect for you, why not look at how they've done it? In the source code [here](https://popcorntime-online.io/js/ui.js?cb=01), look for the function `set_sizes`, at line 193.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox for this

```
.movies_wrapper {
  display: 'flex'; flex-direction: 'row'; align-items: 'stretch';
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x0vLgfar/